# ¿Se puede decir "la amistad que los ha unido durante LOS/ESTOS largos años se ha ruinado"?

Tags: gramática

¿Es correcta la siguiente oración?

> La amistad que los ha unido durante **los/estos** largos años se ha ruinado

La oración original es:

> La amistad que los ha unido durante largos años se ha ruinado

Esta oración la he encontrado en línea.

Comment: nótese que se dice _se ha arruinado_. Por otra parte, sería interesante que explicaras tu pensamiento al proponer estas alternativas: ¿qué te parece a ti?

Comment: @fedorqui yo pensé lo mismo, pero resulta que _[ruinar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WoZ2p0d)_ existe y equivale a "destruir".

Comment: @Charlie ¡ostras! Y mirando en el Mapa de diccionarios veo que hasta 1925 constaba como sinónimo de _Arruinar_. Luego en 1992 se cambió por _Destruir, arruinar_ y finalmente en 2001 por el _Destruir_ actual.

Comment: Creo que "los" como un objeto directo, solo puede ser utilizado correctamente cuando los años son especificados. 

al decir "durante los largos años" estas hablando de TODOS los largos año. 

como saber si utilizer "los" o no. 

la frase responde a la pregunta "¿Cuales?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link to the original text is not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas que "los largos" sería "estos largos", ya que parecería que hay años largos unos mas que otros. Al referirte a "estos" haría una distinción de que han sido los últimos relativos a ese momento.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones.